# Styling elements in a block of adjacent elements with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

In some article text, images are wrapped in `p.img` tags, which individually are topped and tailed with a border and some padding:

```
p.img {
    border-top: 1px dotted #414042;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #414042;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

However, when a bunch of images appear in succession, like so:

```
<p class="img"><img ...></p>
<p class="img"><img ...></p>
<p class="img"><img ...></p>
<p class="img"><img ...></p>
```

I only want the padding-top and border-top to apply to the first `p.img` in the group, and `padding-bottom` and `border-bottom` to the last `p.img` in the group. The `p.img' need to have all borders and padding removed.

I tried experimenting with `p.img + p.img` adjacent selectors, but I cannot affect the first and last `p.img` in the group.

If anyone can help me achieve this using CSS only that would be great, before I resort to JS.

**Edit**
A few are suggesting I use first-child and last-child selectors, but I don't want to affect any p.img that are not part of a group of adjacent p.imgs. I.e. this wouldn't work (in sass)

```
p.img + p.img {
        border-top: 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 0;

        &:first-child {
            border-bottom: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }

        &:last-child {
            border-top: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
        }

    }
```

My article might look like this:

```
article 
    p
    p
    p.img
    p
    p.img
    p.img
    p.img
    p
```

It's only the p.img in the group of three I want to style; not the first, individual one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you’ve got a flat background colour you could negative margins and a solid top border to cover up the previous `p`s dotted bottom border:

```
p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
p.img {
  border-top: 1px dotted #414042;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #414042;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
p.img+p.img {
  margin-top: -21px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

where `#fff` is your background colour. Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/n7P5d/

Comment: No probs. The takeaway is that CSS can’t (yet) select up or back on the tree, just forwards and down. If you find yourself needing to refer back to a previous element then you need to think about faking the effect with the currently selected one.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use css3? (i.e. do you need to support older versions of IE?)

If you can, you can use [`:first-child` and `:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) selectors.

These will do exactly what you want, but [are lacking support.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) in IE8 and down.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to target only those p.imgs in the group. For instance I tried:

    p.img + p.img {
   border-top: 0;
   border-bottom: 0;
   padding-top: 0;

   &:first-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
   }

   &:last-child {
    border-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
   }

  }

Comment: `.img:first-child` will select the first element with the class of `.img`

Comment: But I don't want to affect p.imgs that aren't part of the adjacent group

Comment: Then just add a parent beforehand like `#parent p.img:first-child`. This says to only use the first `<p>` inside `#parent` with the class `.img`

Comment: @Andy: No, it selects an element if it's the first child of its parent and it has that class. Not just the first element that has that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
p.img {
    border-top: 1px dotted #414042;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #414042;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

p.img:first-child {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

p.img:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` selectors.

As Andy says though, browser support will be your sticking point.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: So:

    p.img:first-of-type { padding-top: 10px; border-top: 1px solid black }
    p.img:last-of-type { padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black }

Answer (score 0):

Now you've updated it, and looking at your article structure, will you always know how images are grouped? If it's manual couldn't you just add a bit of extra css and create a new class such as:

p.img {

}

p.img-first {
  border-top:
{

p.img-last {
  border-bottom:
}

So your articles would now be:

article 
    p
    p
    p.img
    p
    p.img-first
    p.img
    p.img-last
    p

However, if it's not manual and you're not sure how images will appear, JS is teh only option.